# using JWT token with users and apps

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

Hi guys I need this specific authorization on JWT tokens,

---

Scenario - In my application I have X number of apps and Y number of users. An app can have only 1 user and users can have many apps.
I'm using JWT and securing the users belong to the application but now I want to secure the APIs that a user can't change other user's apps.

I have two solutions and both are not much feasible and I want to know if there is a better way to do this.

---

1st solution :  when an user authenticating attach list of owned app ids to the encrypted token.
Then when making a request with the token you can decode and check if the request is to change his owned app.
this works but the problem is when an user get more and more apps token becomes a very long string. (I believe at some point it does not support)

---

2nd solution: when an user make a request, take his user id and check it against the db documents.which is an extra db request I would not like to have.

---

So apart from this any way that I can do this?

Note: in the token I have `userId` and `userRole`.

Comment: when you use 1st one, you are working your middlewares true, then you can create custom JWT token as you wish..    when 2nd solution, your are trying to work out of middlewares. that's not wrong. but it's not a good practice.

Comment: @KavinduChathuranga yes indeed, so do you have any solution to this particular scenario? I'm having lot of traffic already and 2nd one indeed not a good practice.